# Cordova platform add android Command finished with error code 0

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to build my project with cordova command line but it keeps giving error code 0 all the time, it is not clear what that means, I tried to remove the platform then add it to my project with no luck,

```
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    Package: com.test.someproject
    Name: someproject
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-22
Copying template files...
Android project created with cordova-android@4.1.1
Command finished with error code 0: /Users/someone/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/4.1.1/package/bin/create --cli,/Users/someone/NetBeansProjects/someproject/platforms/android,com.test.someproject,someproject
```

Comment: cordova version? node version? if you have node 5 make sure you have cordova 5.4.0

Comment: Cordova ==> 5.4.0
Node ==> 5.0.0

Comment: would you like to share your error log??